# How to fix missing write access error when using remotebuild with cordova ios?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I'm running my ionic cordova project and build ios version using visual taco remotebuild, and I have an error when building my app. It seems related to directory permissions. How to fix this error?

[image]

This is for Visual Studio 2017, Xcode 9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this error by following [this](https://github.com/brunolau/vs-taco-update) to upgrade vs tool set version 7.1.0 and everything work fine.